Can you use the same MX record for two mail servers?
Can you use the same MX record for two mail servers, although not have one mail server receive the same emails if both mail servers are IMAP by setting the mail server name to a higher priority in one of the mail servers?

No. The server with highest priority will be given the email, and only if that server could not be reached, will it fall back to the other server, but its not the same MX record, they are 2 different MX records.

I need two separate MX records, bummer.
